# Nuget intermediary for faster updates

Tags: nuget, package-managers

Let's say my company creates:

1. a commercial product **"Product"**
2. a free opensource library **"Library"**

**"Library"** is published on Nuget for other people.

**"Library"** is also used by **"Product"** also via a nuget reference.

Sometimes we find an urgent bug in **"Library"**, that we need to fix and release updates to both **"Library"** and **"Product"**.

We fix the bug, publish the fix to Nuget.... aaaahnd then we have to wait a couple of hours until nuget publishes the fixed version.

How do teams usually solve this problem elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are several ways to solve such problems. But the way, we used in our project is to not use NuGet for such dependencies. We place such **"Libraries"** in the separate project, that is a part of a **"Product"** repository, or **"Product"** repository refer to this **"Library"** with [git-modules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). The build process of product in this case would be:

1. Build **"Library"** -> *after this publishing process to nuget started automatically in the separate job (speaking about automation build on Jenkins)*
2. Build **"Product"** using built **"Library"**
3. Publish **"Product"**

In this piplene additional built options like *"Building and publishing only library"* will be helpfull in your build scripts.

If you refer to **"Library"** as to git submodule, so all staff, connected with library build and publishing can be placed there. So I recomment use git submodule for this. Also with git submodule it will be easier to mange version of **"Library"** that you want to use in your **"Product"**

Answer (score 0):

[You can create own *"Nuget package source"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) somewere in the cloud, or in your company network. And, on building your **"Library"**, publish it in both sources: nuget.org and your own one. So, in your internal projects you will use your package source an be able to receive updates right after publishing, but other users of this **"Library"** will able to include it in their project with regular nuget.org.